# Nodejs handlebar render empty webpage

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I'm a newbie in nodejs and i'm learning to use handlebars to render a website.

Here is my routing (inside index.js)

```
app.get('/house', function (req, res) {

    var houses = [
        {
            name: "House a",
            address: "Address a",
            price: "Price a"
        },
        {
            name: "House b",
            address: "Address b",
            price: "Price b"
        },
        {
            name: "House c",
            address: "Address c",
            price: "Price c"
        }
    ]
    res.render('house', houses);
})
```

Here is my house.handlebars

```
<div class="row">
    {{#each houses}}
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <p>Name: {{name}}</p>
        <p>Address: {{address}}</p>
        <p>Price: {{price}}</p>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

The problem is when i go to http://localhost:3000/house, the page is all white and render nothing. I inspected the site and notice that everything inside {{each houses}} and {{/each}} disappear. 
I'm wondering what are the problems here. 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object structure is incorrect. try this:

```
res.render('house', {houses: houses});
```